# Yii2, обращение к методу модели

Tags: php, yii2

Есть ли простой способ обратиться к методу модели в Yii2? Что-то вроде:

```
$a = User::model()->method();
```

Запись вида

```
$a = new User()->method();
```

Не срабатывает.

Answer (score 2):

Если же хочешь использовать методы проще (не знаю чем именно это обусловлено), то можно метод сделать static:

```
public static function method () {...}
```

и потом обращаться к нему как `User::method()`.

Если простой в том случае, как ты спрашиваешь - имеется ввиду в одну строку?
В данном случае нет. И в доке всегда пишут так:

```
$a = new User();
$a->method();
```

Сначала инициализация класса, а потом обращение к методу.

Answer (score 2):

Начиная с php 5.4 (емнип) доступен следующий вид вызова:

```
$a = (new User)->method();
```

Однако то, что вы пытаетесь сделать, немного идет в разрез с логикой AR. Все методы модели относятся к текущей модели, т.е. к конкретной сущности. Вы же пытаетесь получить какие-то данные, которые к сущности не привязаны, и, следовательно, этот метод не должен принадлежать модели. Скорее всего, вам действительно нужен либо статичный доступ, либо вообще вынести этот функционал из модели.